# HTML Form action ?dir=directory&q=

Tags: html, forms

I got a question how to make a from output &q=something

cause now its localhost/index.php?dir=directory

And my form just overwrites the  localhost/index.php?dir=directory to  localhost/index.php?q=something

But I want to get localhost/index.php?dir=directory&q=something

Can u forward me to a tutorial or something? Don't know how to find this up on the net

Thanks.

Comment: It may help if you post the code you are currently using.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MKLtw4jR the url at startup is http://127.0.0.1/3/index.php?dir=Mietek%2F

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form with `method="get"` (the default) will overwrite any query string specified in the action.

Don't hardcode the data in the query string, put it in `<input type="hidden">` elements instead.

Comment: You could always just post data too, I don't see why people would want to use get anyways unless its for user readability of the url.

Comment: I have <form action="index.php" method="get"><input name="q"
type="hide"> <input type="submit"></form> and still does the same ?q=

Comment: It is `type="hidden"` and you have to specify a value if you want it to have a value. `<input type="hidden" name="q" value="something">`